# MongoDB - If Lng/Lat in Polygon, Return Document

Tags: mongodb

I have Mongo database filled with Polygons of neighbourhood/districts. I need to query **Lng/Lat** that is being supplied by Google, and see if it's within one of the Polygons that I have saved. If coords are within polygon, then return document.

Sounds simple enough, but I've spent hours through Mongo documentation and questions on SO and haven't been able to get it working. Would anyone happen to have an example to get this rolling? If the data in my MongoDB is not structured correctly, I can re do it. Thanks for the help!

**Coords for Kirkland, Quebec, Canada (Lng/Lat):**

```
[-73.8667, 45.4500]
```

**Polygon for Kirkland (From MongoDB Document):**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5277fff17fd78c0a7c713524"),
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "name" : "Kirkland",
    "coordinates" : "[[[-73.84639065099992, 45.46254541400003], [-73.84527964099993, 45.46145258000007], [-73.84492842099989, 45.46110707200006], [-73.84399219399995, 45.460186141000065], [-73.8407852819999, 45.45713777800006], [-73.8405644799999, 45.45693077300007], [-73.84052262699993, 45.45689154900003], [-73.84039886599993, 45.45677551000006], [-73.8390040189999, 45.45539976500004], [-73.83699086899992, 45.45341401400009], [-73.83676532899995, 45.453279922000036], [-73.83636951599993, 45.453044617000046], [-73.83427161599991, 45.45084861200007], [-73.8342537289999, 45.45083099300007], [-73.8331441099999, 45.449854249000055], [-73.83297374799992, 45.44970432200006], [-73.83352648699992, 45.44965909500007], [-73.83523820199991, 45.449519043000066], [-73.83524912799992, 45.449514374000046], [-73.83216772499992, 45.44544321700004], [-73.8355026019999, 45.44561350100008], [-73.83846350499994, 45.44558108000007], [-73.85080954599994, 45.44551408400008], [-73.85188162999992, 45.44536892000008], [-73.85520924199994, 45.44378610100006], [-73.86009216899991, 45.441481287000045], [-73.86010980599991, 45.44147187300007], [-73.86465916499992, 45.43904399200005], [-73.86704282299989, 45.44129004300004], [-73.86713420799992, 45.441376121000076], [-73.8682983409999, 45.442844182000044], [-73.8714420469999, 45.44173971100008], [-73.87279950999994, 45.44269945600007], [-73.87357053799991, 45.44242102800007], [-73.87501784999995, 45.44194323100004], [-73.8751774669999, 45.44189320100008], [-73.87618104099994, 45.44167523200008], [-73.87689832799992, 45.44151941900009], [-73.87549164599994, 45.43840867000005], [-73.87912949699995, 45.43819043500008], [-73.87997818499991, 45.43964749200006], [-73.8809716369999, 45.43921851400006], [-73.88163188499993, 45.438933389000056], [-73.8809365219999, 45.43690093300006], [-73.88340716699992, 45.43647846400006], [-73.8835718649999, 45.437520379000034], [-73.88472633599991, 45.43824372600005], [-73.88597652399994, 45.43848963100004], [-73.88672857599994, 45.43694512900004], [-73.88701594699995, 45.43690032900008], [-73.89454723199992, 45.436337964000074], [-73.89486502499994, 45.436824881000064], [-73.89504137699993, 45.43709448800007], [-73.89833881699991, 45.43618887100007], [-73.9009770429999, 45.43541548600007], [-73.90104477099992, 45.43556667800004], [-73.90143217699995, 45.43684144800005], [-73.90167934699991, 45.43765475400005], [-73.90223650199994, 45.438897293000075], [-73.90276059099995, 45.43880354600008], [-73.9038189289999, 45.44054056200008], [-73.90458511899993, 45.44097805100006], [-73.90467561799994, 45.44115400700008], [-73.90472571299995, 45.44162062300006], [-73.90475441299992, 45.441757435000056], [-73.9054071239999, 45.44486542300007], [-73.90512243199993, 45.44499702200005], [-73.90433747899993, 45.445359850000045], [-73.9045754899999, 45.446720749000065], [-73.90251337799992, 45.447330082000065], [-73.90181885899993, 45.44605801200004], [-73.90090750799993, 45.44622671400003], [-73.90116174799994, 45.44671712400009], [-73.89856674399994, 45.44746179100008], [-73.89833317199992, 45.44752881200009], [-73.89513848899992, 45.44700792800006], [-73.8950564729999, 45.44699454300007], [-73.89398644099992, 45.44715665000007], [-73.89246674599991, 45.44754371200008], [-73.8913180319999, 45.448258667000054], [-73.88994770799991, 45.44884568800006], [-73.88962110499993, 45.44901446100005], [-73.8888201539999, 45.44960221200006], [-73.88646183599991, 45.45133264100008], [-73.88641881099994, 45.45136418700008], [-73.88582581199995, 45.451799304000076], [-73.88569238199995, 45.45185328900004], [-73.88550268699993, 45.451930049000055], [-73.88356499199995, 45.452318914000045], [-73.88237926399995, 45.45250981600008], [-73.88159874099995, 45.452708312000084], [-73.8815054879999, 45.45273201200007], [-73.88051679499995, 45.45298343700006], [-73.87270614999994, 45.45706238300005], [-73.86628960799993, 45.46020504200004], [-73.8661233009999, 45.46028485000004], [-73.86623267899995, 45.46039386200004], [-73.86752501599995, 45.461574598000084], [-73.86605950199993, 45.46250052600004], [-73.86332124899991, 45.46413909600005], [-73.8610396759999, 45.465215826000076], [-73.8603632949999, 45.46596386900006], [-73.85726109799992, 45.46835262200005], [-73.8572420289999, 45.468367285000056], [-73.85658503199994, 45.46884818800004], [-73.85484660799995, 45.47030475400004], [-73.85481935299993, 45.47032760400003], [-73.85450828099994, 45.470444332000056], [-73.8533369459999, 45.46918888000005], [-73.8519519109999, 45.46794286400006], [-73.85182828899991, 45.467799712000044], [-73.85127994299995, 45.46724713600008], [-73.85125951999993, 45.467228369000054], [-73.84958285499994, 45.46568497800007], [-73.84955791599992, 45.46566045900005], [-73.84639065099992, 45.46254541400003]]]"
}
```

Comment: What kind of query are you executing? Did you mean for your coordinates to be an Array of Arrays of Arrays? [[[]]] That might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example. Note the following differences to your code:

- the geometry of Kirkland is very simplified. This should not make a difference.
- the polygon must have the same beginning and ending point. Otherwise the query does not work with my installation of mongodb (version 2.4.1).
- the fields named "type" and "coordinates" are wrapped within the same superfield named "doc". I believe this is important. Otherwise the query won't work for me.

  ```
  db.locations.remove();
  db.locations.insert({ 
    loc : { 
      type : "Polygon" ,
      coordinates : [ [ 
          [ -73.8 , 45.4 ] , [ -73.9 , 45.4 ] , 
          [ -73.9 , 45.5 ] , [ -73.8, 45.5 ], [ -73.8 , 45.4 ] ] ]
    } 
  });
  db.locations.find({
    loc: {
      $geoIntersects : {
          $geometry : {
              type : "Point",
              coordinates : [ -73.85 , 45.45 ]
          }
      }
    }
  }).forEach(function(entry) { printjson(entry); } )
  ```